# Rails 3 after form submit with error going to show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 app and after form submit (with error) it's going to the show page.

The URL on edit page:

```
http://localhost:5000/costprojects/509/edit
```

Form page with submit statement:

```
<%= simple_form_for @costproject, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}, :validate => true do |f| %>
...
<%= f.submit 'Submit to Division', :class => 'btn btn-warning' %>
```

Controller code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @costproject.update_attributes(params[:costproject])
    flash[:success] = "Project Submitted"  if @costproject.previous_changes.include?(:submit_date)
    format.html { redirect_to nextpath }
    format.json { render json: @costproject }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @costproject.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

After the submit with an error, the URL is:

```
http://localhost:5000/costprojects/509
```

Why isn't it:

```
http://localhost:5000/costprojects/509/edit
```

I check other forms and this seems to be normal - but, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is decided when you submit the form on the client side, the default is showing the edited records. The success or failure is decided on the server side, so the URL remains unchanged, even when you render the edit form. What you can do is to redirect the client on failure back to the edit page, which means one more roundtrip. Alternatively you can submit the form with AJAX, keeping the user on the edit form, until the answer might redirect him to the show page on success.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your controller to update and then check for errors. If `@costproject.save` fails, just render the edit view.

```
@costproject.update_attributes(params[:costproject])
if @costproject.save
  ..
else
  format.html { render :edit }
  ..
end
```